# Why is the function $f$ in the Radon-Nikodym Theorem written as a derivative?

Tags: measure-theory

I don't understand why $f$ can just be written as the gradient between measures $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. Any intuition behind this would be most helpful.

Comment: It's just formal notation. Consider what the theorem looks like when the underlying measure is Lebesgue measure $dx$.

Comment: I understand in classical calculus that for a function $f(x)$, then $df = \frac{df}{dx} dx$ ... but this is used to show infinitesmal increments\decrements to find the gradient. I don't understand how this is applied for lebesgue and borel measures.

Comment: Wikiepedia states because $f$ "describes the rate of change of density of one measure with respect to another". Why is this?

Comment: I mean that it's just notation to reproduce the relation $f = \int \frac{df}{dx}\, dx$, or at least something similar. It's literally just an arbitrary bit of notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anomoly points out, this is just useful notation, though there is some justification for it. Consider the case where the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{F})$ is such that $\mathcal{F}$ is generated by finitely many atoms $A_1,..,A_n$. Then, if $\nu \ll \mu$ on this space, the function
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{A_i} \frac{\nu(A_i)}{\mu(A_i)}, \ \ \mu(A_i) > 0$$
is a version of the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. (If $\mu(A_i) = 0$, then define the function however you like on $A_i$.)

*Proof*. The function is constant on the atoms of $\mathcal{F}$ and therefore measurable. Now, for $F \in \mathcal{F}$
$$\int_F \sum_{i=1}^n \chi_{A_i} \frac{\nu(A_i)}{\mu(A_i)}d \mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{F \cap A_i} \frac{\nu(A_i)}{\mu(A_i)}d \mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\nu(A_i)}{\mu(A_i)} \mu(F \cap A_i) = \sum_{A_i \subseteq F}\nu(A_i) = \nu(F).QED$$

So, in the finite case, the function that takes the value $\frac{\nu(A)}{\mu(A)}$ on the atoms $A$ of $\mathcal{F}$ is a version of the derivative. This matches the notation used in the general case.